# Access Query Filter Based Off Number Value In String

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with that has a field that is populated with "Hold" Value. The value can be *0001*, *ES* *HSI *, *3999*, *CAN2*EXP* ES*, ETC. I need any record that has a value that has a four digit number to be pulled into a separate query. below is a list of example but the numbers can be any array of a four digit combination. Picture on the right is what I want the results to display.

[image][image]

Comment: There is no consistency in position of 4 digits so extracting from string will be extra tricky. Build a VBA function to do that. Explore RegEx for pattern matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `RegExp`.
You have to add a reference to the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions" to use this.

```
Public Function Get4Digit(Test As String) As String
    Dim Re As Object, Matches As Object
    
    Set Re = New RegExp
    With Re
        .Pattern    = "[0123456789]{4}"
        .Global     = False
    End With

    Set Matches = Re.Execute(Test)
    If Matches.Count > 0 Then
        Get4Digit = Mid(Test, Matches(0).FirstIndex + 1, 4)
    Else
        Get4Digit = ""
    End If
End Function
```

usage:

```
MsgBox Get4Digit("*0014*")      ' -> "0014"
MsgBox Get4Digit("**000***")    ' -> ""
MsgBox Get4Digit("*SBR*3392*")  ' -> "3392"
```

You can use this in any query, like any other function.

More info about RegExp's : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_reg_expressions.htm

Comment: Attila beat me to answer. Can call function in query with or without filter: `SELECT *, Get4Digit(fieldname) AS Num FROM table WHERE Len(Get4Digit(Data))=4;`